# Jenkins pipeline exception when using Date object?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Jenkins v2.126, Groovy plugin v2.0

I have the following in my Jenkinsfile

```
def someFunction() {
  Date today = new Date("yyyy-MM-dd")
  // other statements
}
```

and I get the following exception.

```
ERROR: org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new java.util.Date java.lang.String
```

According to Google searches, I should see something to approve in Manage Jenkins->In Script Approval, but I don't see anything there.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we should approve that script using Manage Jenkins -> In Script Approval.
[image: InScript Approval]

If you are not able to see that to approve the script, we have alternative approach also.

Go to Jenkins Job configuration, at the end of the page you can find a checkbox **"Use Groovy Sandbox"**, uncheck that checkbox then it won't wait for script approval.

But best approach is we should approve the script using Manage Jenkins --> InScript approval.

Comment: Like I said, I do NOT see anything showing up in Manage Jenkins->In-process Script Approval (I'm using an admin account). I can't approve what's NOT there. Additionally, I don't see the "Use Groovy Sandbox" option. This is a Pipeline job. I've Google all these options to no avail.

Comment: verify "Script Security" plugin installed or not. if not install it, then you should be able to see the checkbox in the pipeline and inscript approval in manage jenkins

Comment: Script Security Plugin v1.44 is installed. I think that's a core plugin that's automatically installed now anyway. I installed the Permissive Script Security Plugin, but I don't really want to go that route.